# Powershell replacement for SetSPN

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-3.0

How to get SetSPN to use a specific DC or IP address of a DC? 
To Set Service Principal Names for a Lab account inside the Lab DC from a Jump-Box not part of the Lab domain.

Accomplished with most Powershell AD cmdlets by adding the "-Server" param.

Does not seem possible with SetSPN.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Knowledge Share:

I spent a good part of the last day trying to find ways to get SetSPN to work for me when trying to run from a Jump-box into a network-isolated Lab environment with a clone of the DC.

All the AD/network calls in the rest of my code can specify which server to talk to (powershell ad calls mostly allow for the "-Server 192.168.2.1" to specify the DC within the lab).

But not SetSPN. So for those that have similar issues with SetSPN; or just want to use powershell exclusively, here's a nice easy way to Add an SPN using just Powershell's ActiveDirectory module.

```
Function Add-SPN([string]$SamAccountName,[string]$SPNString, [string]$ADServerName){
    Try{
    $filter = "(SamAccountName -eq '$SamAccountName')";
    $user=get-aduser -Filter $Filter -prop ServicePrincipalNames -Server $ADServerName;
    $Ready=$True;
    if($User.ServicePrincipalNames.Count -gt 0){
        if($User.ServicePrincipalNames.ToUpper().Contains($SPNString.ToUpper())){"Failed. A Matching SPNString Already Exists! ($SPNString) -> ($SamAccountName)";$Ready=$false;}
    }
    if($ready){
        $user|Set-ADUser -ServicePrincipalNames @{Add=$SPNString} -Server $ADServerName;
        if((get-aduser -Filter $Filter -prop ServicePrincipalNames -Server $ADServerName).ServicePrincipalNames.ToUpper().Contains($SPNString.ToUpper())){
            "Successfully Added SPN ($spnstring) -> ($SamAccountName)."
        }else{ throw "Something went wrong, SPNString not found after Set-ADUser succeeded."}
    }
    }catch{throw "Add-SPN: SamAccountName($($SamAccountName)) SPNString($($SPNString))An Error Occurred. $_"}
}

Add-SPN -SamAccountName "SVC_Test_SQL" -SPNString "http/$($WebServer.DNSName)" -ADServerName (get-addomain -Identity $ServerDomain).pdcEmulator
Add-SPN -SamAccountName "SVC_Test_SQL" -SPNString "http/$($WebServer.name)" -ADServerName (get-addomain -Identity $ServerDomain).pdcEmulator
```

The part of the function that actually sets the value, Set-ADUser (from: import-module ActiveDircetory), can be easily modified to Remove, Replace or clear SPN's for a new function or expansion of the above.

```
From: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617215.aspx
To add values:
    -ServicePrincipalNames @{Add=value1,value2,...}
To remove values:
    -ServicePrincipalNames @{Remove=value3,value4,...}
To replace values:
    -ServicePrincipalNames @{Replace=value1,value2,...}
To clear all values:
    -ServicePrincipalNames $null
```

Comment: Quite interesting. One question, though: shouldn't it be with 'Get-ADComputer' instead of 'Get-ADUser'?